# jQuery morphing button concept

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written some jQuery that will morph a button into a container when clicked.
I now want to use the same script but on a different button. I am not sure the best way to do this though. Would it be to copy and paste the whole `morphObject` and then change the bits which need changing for the new button, and then run both the object's init functions?

Here is the Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2a3rp590/

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var morphObject = {

        button: $('button.morphButton'),
        container: $('div.morphContainer'),
        overlay: $('div.overlay'),
        content: $('h1.content, p.content'),

        endPosition: {
            top: 100,
            left: '50%',
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            marginLeft: -300
        },


        init: function() {
            var mO = morphObject,
                button = mO.button;

            button.on('click', function() {
                button.fadeOut(200);
                setTimeout(mO.containerMove, 200);
            });

        },

        containerMove: function() {
            var mO = morphObject,
                content = mO.content,
                overlay = mO.overlay,
                container = mO.container,
                span = $('span.close');

            overlay.fadeIn();

            container.animate(mO.endPosition, 400, function() {
                    content.fadeIn();
                    span.fadeIn();
                    mO.close();
            });

        },

        close: function() {
            var mO = morphObject,
                container = mO.container,
                overlay = mO.overlay,
                content = mO.content;

            if ( container.find('span.close').length ) return;

            $('<span class="close">X</span>').appendTo(container);

            var span = $('span.close');

            overlay.add(span).on('click', function() {
                content.fadeOut();
                span.fadeOut();
                overlay.fadeOut();
                setTimeout(mO.animateBack, 200);
            });

        },

        animateBack: function() {
            var mO = morphObject,
                container = mO.container;
                button = mO.button;

            container.animate(mO.startPosition, 400, function() {
                    button.fadeIn(300);
            });

        }

    }

    var container = morphObject.container;

    morphObject.startPosition = {
        top: container.css('top'),
        left: container.css('left'),
        width: container.css('width'),
        height: container.css('height'),
        marginLeft: container.css('margin-left')
    };

    morphObject.init();

});
```

You can see in the fiddle, I have added a new button, container and content. How can I make my code work with multiple buttons?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `init` can take params and pass it back to the object.

Comment: I don't think that would work in my scenario

Comment: Your scenario is to reuse a piece of object based on different inputs, such as buttons and it'd would very well work.

Comment: Ok, please could you provide a slight example on how to do it? I just can't see how it would all work.

Answer (score 0):

As i said in my comments, you could do the following. Bear in mind that this is an **untested** version.

```
init: function(params) {
    //object reference
    var self = this;
    //reassign the button object if it was passed
    //else use the default from the object
    self.button = typeof params !== "undefined" && params.button || self.button;

    self.button.on('click', function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(200);
        setTimeout(self.containerMove, 200);
    });
}

//I am using an object as you my want to
//pass in more options later, just in case
//such as 
/*
morphObject.init({
    button: $('button.morphButton2'),
    container: $('.another-container')
});
*/

morphObject.init({
    button: $('button.morphButton2')
});
```

Or you could have a common class to all buttons that would trigger the click inside the init method. Easy enough?

```
var morphObject = {
    button: $('button.morphButton') //let's say 'morphButton' is the common class
    .....
    .....

    init: function(params) {
        //object reference
        var self = this;        
        self.button.on('click', function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(200);
            setTimeout(self.containerMove, 200);
        });
    }

    .....
    .....
    .....
}
```

Comment: Well now the buttons are configured to work, but what about the different containers and contents? This code wouldn't know that when a certain button is clicked, a certain container with certain contents will open. Confused...